# docker: npm install on docker start

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'd like to have some kind of "development docker image" in which `npm install` is executed every time I restart my Docker Container (becuase I don't want to build, push and pull the new dev image every day from my local machine to our Docker server).
So I thought I could do sth. like this in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD npm install git+ssh://git@mycompany.de/my/project.git#develop && npm start
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. The container stops immediately after `docker start` and I don't know why, because this works:

```
RUN npm install git+ssh://git@mycompany.de/my/project.git#develop
CMD npm start
```

(Just for testing, that's of course not what I want to have). But maybe I have some wrong perception of `CMD` and someone could enlighten me?

Comment: Can you try `CMD sh -c 'npm install... && npm start'`?

Comment: You could use something like Jenkins to automatically do the building, so all you have to do is push. Or just run docker exec <container> npm update on the contaienr every time you wish to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `CMD` point to a shell script.

```
CMD ["/my/path/to/entrypoint.sh"]
```

with that script being:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install git+ssh://git@mycompany.de/my/project.git#develop
npm start
# whatever else
```

I find this easier for a few reasons:

1. Inevitably these commands increase with more being done
2. It makes it *much* easier to run containers interactively, as you can run them with `docker run mycontainer /bin/bash` and then execute your shell script manually. This is helpful in debugging